# How to write a SQL Loader control file to load data into multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle, upload

I have a data file with 3 different sets of information like this below:

```
@@@08016995BUILD  12/15/04POSITION
"AABPX    ","76826309","M","L","     1509.4340"
----More similar Records_-------------------------
@@@08016995BUILD  12/15/04SECDESC
"AABPX    ","mf","AMERICAN AADVANTAGE BALA","NCED PLAN AHEAD         ","                        ","                        ","  14.4500","121504","   14.4500"
-----More similar Records-----------------------
@@@08016995BUILD  12/15/04CUSTOMER
"xxxxxxx","FINANCIAL SOLUTIONS      ","ACCOUNT             ","xxxxx ST               ","xx            xxxxx","                              ","000-000-0000","xxx-xxx-xxxx","xxxxx","xx","xxxxx","   ","xx","  "," "," "
          ","  14.4500","121504","   14.4500"
-----More similar Records-----------------------
end of data file
```

Now I want to write a control file that would push the first set of data to a position table, second set of data to a sec desc table, and 3rd set of data to a customer table. HOw can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Loader_FAQ#Can_one_load_data_from_multiple_files.2F_into_multiple_tables_at_once.3F